# Home page layout in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce-classic

I'm evaluating to migrate to Lightning Experience. However, I have in my classic home page layout some Dashboards that are relevant to all the sales reps, when I switch to Lightning Experience the home page layout it shows some standard fields. It looks very nice, but the thing is that I'm not using the opportunities standard object, so to show that chart it doesn't make sense.

Does anyone know how to setup your own home page layout for Lightning Experience or at least to hide/show some components?

I attached to pictures showing the two versions of home pages, and I only need to keep something similar to the classic version.

Thanks in advance guys.

Classic:
[image]

Lightning Experience:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is available in Summer 16 release .I just tested in one of the pre-release org on gs0 and this is how it looks

[image]

Edit the Home page layout

[image]

Kindly note its only in Summer 16 release .So if you have a sandbox you can see this now .

Comment: Brilliant...I have my sandbox in Summer 16 release and the option is there....Thank you soo much for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know if is possible to add Dashboards there? as I only see Report Chart and not Dashboards.

Comment: that sounds like another question